# Creating a parallelogram with for loops

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hello I am trying to create a parallelogram and am having a bit a trouble so far I have

```
void stars(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i > j) {
                cout << " ";
            }
            else cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

So stars(7) prints

```
*******
 ******
  *****
   ****
    ***
     **
      *
```

however i need it to print like this

```
*******
 *******
  *******
   *******
    *******
     *******
      *******
```

my function is moving the spaces over correctly but it is decreasing the amount of stars as well, how can i continue to move the stars over but without losing the number of stars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not make printing stars conditional. Print `i` spaces then `n` stars.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        cout << ' ';
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        cout << '*';
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

[live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/SofGo1VjFbOsBgIi)

That being said, this isn't very readable, I'd rather go with: (or Lassie's answer)

```
string nstars(n, '*');
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cout << string(i, ' ') << nstars << '\n';
}
```

[live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LQgZzgfPZeSkulzm)

This creates a `std::string`s of `i` spaces and `n` stars. It carries the cost of additional allocations, but readability is often more important, especially for small toy projects.

And if you're more into stdlib algorithms:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    fill_n(ostream_iterator<char>(cout), i, ' ');
    fill_n(ostream_iterator<char>(cout), n, '*');
    cout << '\n';
}
```

I don't think this should be any worse than the first loop, but it may look scary for newbies.

Comment: Of course, you can make the `string(n, '*')` object once and reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

void stars (int n)
{
    std::string s(n,'*'); // construct it only 1 time
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        std::cout << std::setw(n+i) << s << std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
    stars(7);
}
```

Comment: That's a clever trick with moving `setw`. Maybe edit an explanation into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
void stars(int n)
{
for(int i =0; i < n; i++, cout << "\n")
    for(int j = 0-i; j < n; j++)
        if(j < 0) cout << " ";
        else cout << "*";
}
```